# what is this Yosemite ground cover plant?

Tags: ground-cover

I saw this plant on the ground near Sentinal Dome at Yosemite. Can someone please tell me what it is?  I'd like to try growing it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a Brewer's Lupine (Lupinus Breweri), see the description [here](https://www.americansouthwest.net/plants/wildflowers/lupinus-breweri.html). Clearly a lupin flower, but curious in that it forms a low, prostrate spreading mat of foliage, and silvery-looking due to the hairy surface of the leaves.

Comment: Not sure it is a Lupinus. Here (Europe) we have many similar looking Fabaceae on alpine level. (whiteish leaves, and prostrate: common mountain traits). In any case I will not guess about genus and species of US mountain species.